# Has Politics.SE ever hosted a question criticizing Joe Biden's government?

Tags: discussion

Have Joe Biden fans banned critical questions from him?

Has Politics.SE ever hosted a question criticizing Joe Biden's politics?

For example, his departure from Afghanistan. Strengthen the Taliban. Strengthening Iran's missile program through active diplomacy.

Can the Democratic Party of America be criticized?

[Example](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/66501/where-did-the-budget-of-irans-missile-industry-come-from)

Comment: The question you linked appears to be claiming that Biden and the Democrats are the only reason Iran can make missiles and they should have destroyed the country.

Comment: @Jow W They are not the only reason, but they are the most important reason. After all, the government, today, is them

Comment: Yep sounds like you are pushing an agenda but I already knew that.

Comment: _"After all, the government, today, is them"_ There's not a single elected Republican anywhere? Democrats don't have to negotiate with Republicans on _anything_?

Answer (score 8):

The purpose of Politics Stack Exchange is not to criticize anyone.

As you [can read on the help center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), our mission is to provide **objective** information on politics and political processes and **not** to further opinion or debate. We should not bash *any* political position here. So when a question criticizes a person, organization, faction or idea, then it is probably not a good question for this website.

That does not necessarily mean that the question should not be asked at all on this website. It makes a difference *how* you ask it. For example, the question linked as an example above would probably work out on this site if it didn't clearly take one side in the conflict and portrayed it as the evil and dangerous side. It would probably have worked if it had tried to maintain a neutral point of view and focused on just asking the actual question about the budget of Iran.

Ask for objective information, answer questions with well-balanced facts and let the reader form their own opinion about which political side is right and which is wrong.

Comment: Everyone here is criticizing Trump. Only Joe Biden and the Democrats seem to be the red line.

Comment: @user39108 : If you believe everyone here is criticizing Trump, feel free to link the relevant questions into your post here to give an example of what you mean.

Comment: It is a big fat link [Trump](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tags/donald-trump)

Answer (score 7):

I'd actually prefer to see more good questions about the actions of Biden's administration and Democratic policies more generally put. That's good, solid, somewhat boring policy wonk stuff; meat and potatoes for a site like this. Please feel free to ask such.

Unfortunately — given the current political context — questions about Biden or the Democrats tend not to be 'proper' questions according to the site rules.  They generally fall into two problematic categories:

- Polemical assertions about the character, intentions, or orientations of the Democratic party or its leader that are merely masquerading as questions
- Rampant 'whataboutism' that seems more interested in salvaging and justifying GOP policies and positions than in discovering anything new about Democratic policies and positions

Well-constructed questions get well-constructed answers; poorly constructed questions get removed. That's true regardless of political party or orientation.

Comment: Private companies can not violate freedom of expression. Also in favor of the Democrats.

Comment: birds of feather flock together [Pompeo accuses Biden admin of working to make Iran America's 'senior partner' in Middle East](https://www.foxnews.com/politics/pompeo-biden-admin-iran-partnership-middle-east)

Comment: @user39108: The First Amendment only applies to government policy and legislation. I mean, c'mon: its opening phrase is "Congress shall make no law...". And did you even read that FOX punditry article you linked? Pompeo is (ostensibly) accusing the Biden admin. of being anti-semitic merely for entertaining the idea of diplomatic talks with Iran. Trust FOX to pull out all the Islamophobic stops...

Answer (score 2):

Politics Stack Exchange is not an op ed hosting site. It is not a platform for people to publish long, elaborate criticisms of or philippics against certain political actors that only vaguely disguise as questions.

Questions should, in general:

- ask about the functioning of the political process or governments *in general* without relying on the action of specific actors;
- attempt to understand the general ideas and principles of political ideologies or programmes; or
- attempt to understand reasons that underlie specific actions or utterances by actors as far as these motivations are able to be determined without resorting to too much speculation.

(There are more types of questions that can be good ones and acceptable on this site, but I think those would be three of the main ones.)

Likewise, answers are also not a platform to publish long, elaborate criticisms of or philippics against ... you get the picture. Instead, they should attempt to explain the actions that happen, the rites that underlie, the legal, ideological or political motivations, etc.

Criticisms of the actors can, of course, happen in either questions or answers. However, the point of questions should never be criticisms first, question second; and likewise, the point of answers should never be criticism first, answer second.

Thus, if you are looking for postings that explicitly criticise the current or any former US administration, you are on the wrong site.

---

In this posting, the word 'criticism' and its derivatives can be substituted with an appropriate form of 'praise' at every single point. Just to make that part crystal clear.

Comment: +1 for "philippics". For some reason, it was really funny in this context...

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage to do so. But please keep in mind that you have to be very careful while doing so. Some checklist:

1. Use this symbol > when you are copying something from somewhere. Else your post can get locked.
2. Use a programming language to find how many similar words are there between your latest two questions. A guess would be 50% or more similarity can get your post instantly deleted.

Then the important ones.

1. Ask something that can be answered without speculation.
2. Use reference always. There are a few guys here who would downvote before asking for citation. Activate your clipboard. It's necessary. ☑️
3. Try not to discredit because you are angry. Everyone is angry. Genuine questions can be rephrased. That is the beauty of any language.
4. Read the rules. It is essential. The mods are not always wrong. They make mistakes sometimes. To err is human.
5. Listening is important. There are some very wise people here. Listen, take advice, and try to improve. It saves time, prevents you from getting deleted, and adds to your knowledge.

Comment: “Use a programming language to find how many similar words are there between your latest two questions. A guess would be 50% or more similarity can get your post instantly deleted.” I’ve never heard of this rule, could you please link a reference so I could find out more about it?

Answer (score 0):

#### Maybe

There’s [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/48070/why-is-hunter-biden-s-position-in-burisma-not-considered-a-problem), which (kindaaaa but not really) criticizes Hunter Biden (Joe Biden’s son). Make what you will of that